# Setting up a "hot mic" for a softer vocal sound

Tags: recording

I'm working on developing "my own unique vocal sound" and since I like the sound of my  softer voice I wanted to set up my mic to be able to pick it up without any feedback. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get started  with this? I usually hit a wide variety of notes lows and highs so I'm not sure if I can accomplish getting the sound without having a sound guy to constantly make adjustments or if there are digital harmonizers that would make some adjustments to the system?? Any ideas??

Comment: Feedback should never be a problem in recording. Also, "constantly adjusting" is quite doable with automation. So are you really talking about recording, or rather live performance? If so, please change the tags.

Answer (score 1):

There are several considerations to keep in mind while trying to accomplish your goal. One thing that is important in setting up a "hot" mic is the proper settings on your mixer or amplification system.  If you are using a mixer with both a volume and gain control, you will first want to adjust the gain to the point where you almost but don't quite get feedback singing at the volume that will comprise the majority of your performance.  After you have the gain properly adjusted, you can adjust the volume of the mic channel so that your vocals sit well in the mix with the rest of the music, and then adjust the overall volume of the system for the venue and size of audience and ambient noise etc.  It is also important to be aware of your speaker and monitor positions as it relates to your mic.  If the mic is too close to either a monitor or main speaker, you will get feedback.  Also, be sure that the mic is not pointed towards a speaker or that no speakers are pointed towards the mic.  All of these things will help you get the most volume without feedback.

The other thing you will need to practice on is using the "proximity effect".  You might need to test different microphones to see which work best.  But with the correct mic, you will be able to equalize the volume between softly sung and more loudly sung passages by varying the distance from your mouth to the mic.  When singing softly, get closer to or even "eat" the mic.  (of course this will emphasize the bass frequencies more).  When singing louder, back away from the mic.  A vocal effects processor will allow you to store different pre-set EQ settings for various songs so that if you need to boost the treble on a particular song where you will sing softly, you could do so and name the pre-set after that song.  A harmonizer will even allow you to double your voice - only an octave higher or lower.  TC Helicon makes a number of different vocal effects processors that are reasonably priced.